# testing post load in a httpBackend mock

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to test my service in angular, and I am having difficulty testing the put request. What I want to test is to see that the content of the request is correct.
First attempt is like this:

```
  httpBackend.expectPUT('/data/category/1',newCategory).respond(201,'');
  service.addCategory(newCategory);
  httpBackend.flush();
```

Hoping that newCategory object turn to a json. But it fails:

> ```
>  TypeError: object is not a function
> ```

Another attempt is to use a function for testing the request load:

```
var isNewCategory = function(str){
    return JSON.parse(str) == newCategory;
};
httpBackend.expectPUT('/data/category/1',isNewCategory).respond(201,'');
service.addCategory(newCategory);
httpBackend.flush();
```

This produces :

> Error: Expected PUT /data/category/1 with different data
>      EXPECTED: function (str){
>              return JSON.parse(str) == newCategory;
>            }
>      GOT:      {"name":"new category","id":"2","parentId":"1"}
>          at $httpBackend (C:/Users/abizhanzadeh@cta.loc/Documents/work

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: the second param is the object/data you expect to be in the PUT request.  What is newCategory in the first example?

Comment: It is just an object that I want to post to the backend as json